# Was there any of the need, which was not recognized as need, but accidentally allowed to ease any of the desired action/conformation?

Tags: evolution

I am searching data on whether we are able to recognize all the needs, or ease allowing actions, for the attainment of any of desired action/conformation or not.

Was there any of the need, which was not recognized as need, but accidentally allowed to ease any of the action, and then later got to be known as the need? If there are any, why were we not able to recognize them before?

Answer (score 3):

I need to know what do you mean by a **need**, does it mean, something that we need for our survival or something that has a great importance in our life?
I think, **fire** is such a thing. The discovery of fire, or, it's controlled use was a major milestone in the history of Mankind.
There was no idea then that fire would be used for cooking food, or making food easy to digest until it was discovered. And *now*, it is surely a need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Such unknown needs seem to be new experiences which we had not known before (?).

Comment: Need = Conformations/structures which allow attaining certain conformations/desired-utility in an optimal way?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer ok, now I understand what do you mean by a need. I do not have any idea other than fire right now. You shall wait for more answers.